# update using execute immediate in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
v_var1 := varchar2(100);
v_var2 := varchar2(100);
v_var3 := varchar2(100);
v_var4 := varchar2(100);

BEGIN

v_var1 := 'col';
v_var2 := 'val1';
v_var3 := 'val2';
v_var4 := 'vall3';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TABLENAME SET '|| v_var1 ||' = :v_var2  WHERE ID =  :v_var3 AND COUNTRY =  :v_var4'
USING v_var2,v_var3,v_var4;

END;
```

Is it possible to set the column to be updated dynamically? It is throwing an error

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 8: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "="
>   when expecting one of the following

. Checked other posts but able to find only how to pass table name dynamically. Any thing wrong in this script?

Comment: Please post your real code. There is nothing wrong in your example code.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Real code is no different. Here it is,

Comment: DECLARE
v_var1 := varchar2(100);
v_var2 := varchar2(100);
v_var3 := varchar2(100);
v_var4 := varchar2(100);

BEGIN

v_var1 := 'AOR_2001';
v_var2 := '12345';
v_var3 := '12345';
v_var4 := 'US';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE CON.DEPT_TOP_STACK_TABLE SET '|| v_var1 ||' = :v_var2  WHERE LVL1_ORGANIZATION_ID = :v_var3 AND COUNTRY =  :v_var4'
USING v_var2,v_var3,v_var4;

END;

Comment: remove `:=` s in the declaration

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting new information as comment. Try `sqlstr := 'UPDATE TABLENAME SET '|| v_var1 ||' = :v_var2  WHERE ID =  :v_var3 AND COUNTRY =  :v_var4';` and `DBMS_OITPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlstr);` before you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like this:

```
DECLARE
v_var1 varchar2(100);
v_var2 varchar2(100);
v_var3 varchar2(100);
v_var4 varchar2(100);

BEGIN

v_var1 := 'col';
v_var2 := 'val1';
v_var3 := 'val2';
v_var4 := 'vall3';
...
```

or

```
DECLARE
v_var1 varchar2(100) := 'col';
v_var2 varchar2(100) := 'val1';
v_var3 varchar2(100) := 'val2';
v_var4 varchar2(100) := 'vall3';

BEGIN

...
```

Comment: Sorry, Thats really a very bad mistake. Will remove this question.